# .mll file doesn't work on another user's computer - maya 2019

Tags: c++, api, dll, maya, mel

I'm a newbie at maya c++ API making.

I made a byte of maya c++ api to my computer with Visual studio.
My `.mll` filetype worked well on my computer with devkit using `mel(loadPlugin ~~)`.

But when the code is run on other computer, it doesn't work. I get the error:

```
//Error: line 2: Unable to dynamically load : C:/Users/user/Documents/maya/2018/scripts/outOfcameraAPI.mll
```

Someone told me to bring the `dll` file to other computer, but I can't understand yet.

I'm sure this is very easy to fix for someone but it is making me crazy.  If somebody who reads this knows how to fix, please let me know.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi Olivia and welcome. These types of error have two reasons in most cases: 1. Build in debug mode, not release mode. Debug mode will rely on debug libraries which are only available if the development environment is installed on the computer, e.g. VisualStudio. 2. The plugin needs an additional library, e.g. a alembic reader will need the alembic library.

Comment: thanks to your help. I will change the code after work. I really appreciate it

Comment: I solved the problem. I set the project properties- c/c++ -code generation - runtime - multi-threaded(/MT)
this setup bring .dll to other computer.
 In my case I use release x64. thanks to your help and thanks to god!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of error have two reasons in most cases: 1. Build in debug mode, not release mode. Debug mode will rely on debug libraries which are only available if the development environment is installed on the computer, e.g. VisualStudio. 2. The plugin needs an additional library, e.g. a alembic reader will need the alembic library.